# Mouse disappears in VirtualBox

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtualbox, mouse

I had VB 4.2.8 installed on Mavericks and was working just fine till today, when I suddenly lost the visibility of the mouse pointer in the Guest OS window (Unubtu 13.10). I know that mouse quirks are usually associated with the Guest Additions and VB 4.3.6 reminder window has been pestering me for some time now, so I decided to upgrade.

Situation went worse - now the VM could not see:

```
/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
```

saying that it cannot mount it.

So, I know that it is in /media/cdrom BUT it wasn't there, it was actually mounted under:

```
/media/<uid>/VBOXADDITIONS_4.3.6_91406
```

So, I cd-ed there and:

```
sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

and installed it manually.

Mouse pointer STILL not visible.

If I guess the position, it actually does what is supposed to do - i.e. the mouse pointer IS actually in the Guest , but is NOT visible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Oops! formatting issue :( /media/my_user_name/VBOXADDITIONS_4.3.6_91406

Comment: Well, I shut down the Ubuntu VM one last time and decided just for the heck of it to pop-up a xubunu I installed several months ago just to try it. GUESS WHAT - mouse pointer JUST works!  Gotta be some Ubuntu update that I installed yesterday :( I am sick of Ubuntu being such an unpredictable piece-of-[plug_your_favorite_description_here] lately. On to the "latest Ubuntu screw-ups" forum :(